# Build error in Visual Studio with assembly

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, build

I have the Visual Studio Express 2015 and I try to learn Assembly with the Kip Irvine package. When I try to build the Project I always got an error message. It's code is LNK1104 and the message is cannot open file 'C:\Irvine\Examples\Project32\Debug\Project.exe'.
The code opened is the AddTwo.asm file from the package.

```
; AddTwo.asm - adds two 32-bit integers.
; Chapter 3 example

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.code
main proc
    mov eax,5               
    add eax,6           

    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

I tried build it with listing file and without it, tried to copy the asm file to the Project32 folder and Build that one but the error is always the same.

Comment: What is your type project? C/C++?

Comment: Assuming that the directory (`C:\Irvine\Examples\Project32\Debug`) exists then it could be that the file is locked. Sometimes this can happen if you abort a debugging session abnormally. Sometimes the previous executable is still running in memory. I'd first check to see in task manager if there is a copy of `Project.exe` already running and killing it, and if need be close and reopen Visual Studio if the proble still persists.

Comment: The project type should be C++.
I couldn't find project.exe in the task manager, sometimes visual studio build the project and run it but most of the times I got the error message.